# C++ static pointer to function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, static

I would like to have a private static pointer to a function in my class. Basically, it would look like this:

```
//file.h
class X {
private:
    static int (*staticFunc)(const X&);
    ...
public:
    void f();

};


//file.cpp
void X::f()
{
    staticFunc(*this);
}
```

This gives me an "unresolved external symbol" error. I know that static members must be initialized in the .cpp too, I've tried this:

```
int (X::*staticFunc)(const X&) = NULL;
```

but this gives me an "initializing a function" error. It gives me an uglier error if I try to initialize it with an existing function. Without "= NULL", I get the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `staticFunc = NULL;` in the .cpp file? (Note: This is me forgetting if you have to redeclare the type in the .cpp file, sorry)

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the code on the run. I corrected it now, of course I was passing a parameter to staticFunc when using it. And I was actually writing in the .cpp file "int (X::*staticFunc)(const X&)" instead of "int (*X::staticFunc)(const X&)". Thanks a lot for your answers, it was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//file.cpp  
int (*X::staticFunc)(const X&);

void X::f()  
{  
staticFunc(*this);  
}
```

Comment: Yep.  Spelling it out, a `static` data member declaration in a class is *just* a declaration -- it also needs a separate *definition* outside of the class, in exactly 1 translation unit (source code file).

Comment: You can add an initializer `= NULL` or `= &someFunc` to the `X::staticFunc` definition.  The name of the static member you want to initialize is `X::staticFunc`, so you need to qualify it that way. Without the `X::`, C++ thought you were creating a different declaration.

Comment: '= NULL' is redundant. This is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

It's a member of X, so you need to say

```
int (*X::staticFunc)(const X&) = NULL;
```

Otherwise, you'd just create a global variable called `staticFunc` which is not related to that static member of X.

Answer (score 0):

Couple problems here.

First error is that you're not passing a parameter in your attempt to use staticFunc.  This should cause a compiler error that you're not reporting.

Second issue is that your syntax is wrong.  TonyK got that one.